# How can I preserve my scheduled series when moving from the MS/Rovi guide to EPG123?

Tags: windows-media-center

Like many others, I've recently been having issues with the guide data failing to update in Windows Media Center. So it looks like I'll have to bite the bullet and move to [EPG123](http://epg123.garyan2.net/) and Schedules Direct.

Problem is... I have several hundred series scheduled to record. A tiny handful are based on keyword-matches, so [I should be able to re-import them](http://www.thegreenbutton.tv/forums/viewtopic.php?p=119081#p119081) - but the vast majority are directly linked to IDs in the Rovi guide data, so they won't be recognized once I switch over (I tested this, hoping it would work - they'll show up as scheduled, but won't actually match anything in the schedule).

WMC reports I have over 400 series scheduled right now; a great many of these are duplicates (I inadvertently restored backups twice the last time I reinstalled and never bothered to fix it; also the usual cruft that accumulates when working around issues with corrupt guide data here and there over the years). Still, as a rough guess, I'd say there are somewhere between 150 and 200 unique series, many not currently airing (off season or end of run) and quite a few scheduled to record in the next day or so - I really don't want to dedicate hours to slogging through the XML backups entering them manually!

Is there any way to preserve these without a tremendous amount of manual data-entry?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Grab the last backup of your scheduled recordings from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\eHome\mcepgN-N\backup\recordings\` and put it somewhere safe. Give it a name like `series recording schedule.xml`, just so you don't forget what it is; the name WMC gives it isn't particularly descriptive.
2. Follow [the steps to install and configure EPG123](http://epg123.garyan2.net/?page_id=503), wiping out your recording schedule in the process.
3. Use this bit of script to generate "Click-to-Record" files from the backup you retrieved in Step #1: http://output.jsbin.com/norexazopa

   Just feed it the file and then scroll to the end and click Download all - it'll download a separate file for every *unique* series. Alternately, go through the generated list and download just the ones you want to keep.
4. Go through the `.c2r` files you downloaded and double-click 'em in Explorer. It'll feed the data into WMC which will then try to schedule the show.

Caveats: this falls apart if you somehow end up *renumbering* your channels. Also, there does not appear to be a way to include per-series settings for early-start or late-ending; WMC rejects the files if I include that information. I've also noticed it conviguring some series as "SD-only" in rare cases, though I can't figure out why. Also, it's a lot of clicking; I could've thrown together a small C# program to feed these in, but that seemed like it'd be a bit of work for something I only have to do once; if anyone's motivated, the instructions are on MSDN.

Comment: More info on "Click to record": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb189583.aspx

Comment: So if I, oh I don't know, installed EPG and didn't make that backup and all my scheduled recordings are gone, is there anything I can do?  My series are still in the list, but there is nothing scheduled.

Comment: If you used the Clean Start option in EPG123, [it will have saved a backup as well](http://www.thegreenbutton.tv/forums/viewtopic.php?p=119430#p119430) that you can refer to. If you didn't - and from the sound of it you may not have since the entries are still in the list - then WMC should still be generating backups that contain them, in the path I noted above, @JPhi1618. Generate the C2R files from it, then use WMC to clear scheduled recordings (from settings) and re-import them.